# How can I fix my out of bounds exception in my recursive backtracker maze?

Tags: java, maze, recursive-backtracking

My cells each have a coordinate. My problem is that when my current cell is a border-cell and my random chosen neighbor is not within the border I get an exception. How do I prevent this method from looking outside the border? I tried to add x and y, then checking if the sum of x and y is less than zero then break from the switch case and start all over by looking for a neighbor cell that does exist.

```
public void generate(Maze mz) {
    Random rand = new Random();

    // generate a x * y grid of cells
    StdDraw.setXscale(0, 10);
    StdDraw.setYscale(0, 10);

    // start at initial cell and push it to the stack
    Coord currentCell = new Coord(0,0);
    stack.push(currentCell);

    int remaining = 1;
    while(remaining <= mz.getCols() * mz.getRows()) {
        // check if currentCell's neighbors have been visited
        loop: if(!stack.contains(currentCell.getNeighbor(Direction.NORTH)) || !stack.contains(currentCell.getNeighbor(Direction.WEST)) || !stack.contains(currentCell.getNeighbor(Direction.SOUTH)) || !stack.contains(currentCell.getNeighbor(Direction.EAST))) {
            // choose a random neighbor
            // TODO: special case when cell is on the border
            int randomDirection = rand.nextInt(4);
            switch(randomDirection) {
            case 0:
                int x0 = currentCell.getNeighbor(Direction.NORTH).getCol();
                int y0 = currentCell.getNeighbor(Direction.NORTH).getRow();
                int sum0 = x0 - y0;
                if(sum0 < 0) {
                    break loop;
                }
                mz.setExit(currentCell, Direction.NORTH, true);
                currentCell = currentCell.getNeighbor(Direction.NORTH);
                stack.push(currentCell);
                remaining++;
                break;
            case 1:
                int x1 = currentCell.getNeighbor(Direction.WEST).getCol();
                int y1 = currentCell.getNeighbor(Direction.WEST).getRow();
                int sum1 = x1 - y1;
                if(sum1 < 0) {
                    break loop;
                }
                mz.setExit(currentCell, Direction.WEST, true);
                currentCell = currentCell.getNeighbor(Direction.WEST);
                stack.push(currentCell);
                remaining++;
                break;
            case 2:
                int x2 = currentCell.getNeighbor(Direction.SOUTH).getCol();
                int y2 = currentCell.getNeighbor(Direction.SOUTH).getRow();
                int sum2 = x2 - y2;
                if(sum2 < 0) {
                    break loop;
                }
                mz.setExit(currentCell, Direction.SOUTH, true);
                currentCell = currentCell.getNeighbor(Direction.SOUTH);
                stack.push(currentCell);
                remaining++;
                break;
            case 3:
                int x3 = currentCell.getNeighbor(Direction.EAST).getCol();
                int y3 = currentCell.getNeighbor(Direction.EAST).getRow();
                int sum3 = x3 - y3;
                if(sum3 < 0) {
                    break loop;
                }
                mz.setExit(currentCell, Direction.EAST, true);
                currentCell = currentCell.getNeighbor(Direction.EAST);
                stack.push(currentCell);
                remaining++;
                break;
            }
        } else {
            currentCell = stack.peek();
            stack.pop();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When considering boundary conditions, the technique is to guard against a possible movement out of bounds.

The four boundary conditions are:

- North:  You may move north if you are not already on the top row
- South:  You may move south if you are not already on the bottom row
- East:  You may move east if you are not already on the right most col
- West:  You may move west if you are not already on the left most col

Translating to code, it might look something like this:

```
case 0:  // Want to move North
    // To move north, must be below the top row
    int curRow = currentCell.getRow();
    if(curRow == 0) {   // Assuming top row is assigned to zero
        break loop;
    }
```

Alternatively, something like:

```
case 0:  // Want to move North
    // To move north, must be below the top row
    int curRow = currentCell.getRow();
    if(curRow > 0) {   // Assuming top row is assigned to zero
        // Process the move NORTH
    }
```

The case for SOUTH is similar `if (curRow < MAXROW) { .. process ... }`

For EAST/WEST valid moves are based on the current column.

Comment: Ian, thanks for the reply. I know exactly what you mean. But I implemented this idea and still no luck. I'm starting to think that the boundary condition may not be the problem. I am no longer getting an error, I'm just getting a blank screen. Thank anyway

Comment: It is likely that you had a boundary problem (at least based on the code I see above), and with that problem resolved, you have a problem with the maze generation algorithm in general.  If I can help, let me know otherwise good luck